# Do semaphores require syscalls?

Tags: kernel, cpu, privileges, system-calls, semaphore

I'm preparing for an exam regarding operating systems by doing past exams. It's mostly about Unix systems, the C programming language, and it mentions POSIX a lot, so it's probably best to ask this question here.

The problem is:

> Give three disadvantages of simple spinlocks and/or semaphores. Explain how the respective other mechanism improves on the problem.

One of the 3 disadvantages given + explanation is this:

> Semaphores require a system call even when the thread may proceed immediately. (0.5 P) Spinlocks on the other hand can be implemented completely in userspace and do not require syscalls. They are very efficient for short wait times. (0.5 P)

Why would semaphores require syscalls? Do they have to be in kernel space? Do they require execution of privileged instructions?

Both single-processor and multi-processor systems need to be considered.

Comment: I will give you a hint: what is a semaphore and how it can be implemented? I advise in some questions to try to understand them, and not memorize answers, at least if you have interest in the subject.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am interested in the subject and can think both of ways of implementing it in user space and of ways of implementing it in kernel space. I do understand that a syscall is required **if** the process calling `wait()` on the semaphore has to wait (e.g. the semaphore is fully used) and **if** the one-to-one threading model is used to yield. However, other than that, I don't see why the OS would have to get involved. The solution literally says: "Semaphores require a system call even when the thread may proceed immediately." **The exam is tomorrow**,so I'd appreciate a quick answer.

Comment: You have got special system calls for semaphores http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node51.html or in as a poor man semaphore you can even have a file, or even a variable in shared memory for instance...I would advise some of the doubts to be clarified with the professor(s), as often they have their particular interpretations of the subject, and give more points to their opinions.

Comment: Note the solution is objectively wrong. futexes are designed to support semaphores, and to do so *without* requiring system calls in the un-contended case.

Comment: I dispute the answer that semaphores require a syscall in any case. Only if you deal with processes that are mutually not trustworthy you need the kernel to supervise the semaphores. In this case using semaphores requires a syscall. If you have processes that "stick to the rules" then semaphores may be implemented and used in user space.

Comment: @countermode Semaphores do require a system call in almost all realistic scenarios. A system call can be avoided in the uncontended case, but sleeping requires a system call.

Comment: @Gilles correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some historical context will make things clearer. Semaphores were originally part of the System V inter process communication package (System V IPC), before POSIX IPC was a thing. The names probably give you a clue as to where things are heading; the original use case was locks shared by cooperating processes. (I'm 99.99% percent sure IPC predated threads by quite a while.)

POSIX semaphores work with processes or threads, hence the OS involvement. Context is important here because the answer is clearly about the standard semaphore implementation, not the abstract concept of a semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, semaphores require system calls except in very special scenarios. A semaphore has to be able to wait for the other contenders to free the resource. Waiting requires a system call.

If the contenders on the lock have access to a shared memory space and they trust each other to respect the semaphore protocol, which is mostly the case when the lock is between threads of the same process, then a lock doesn't always need a system calls: it can use unprivileged processor instructions to inspect and change the lock state. This allows acquiring the lock if it's free, and releasing the lock, but waiting for the lock to be free is another matter.

A spinlock keeps busy (“spins”) until the lock becomes free. If the threads contending for the lock are known to run on different CPUs, this may be a valid strategy. If the threads might run on the same CPU then the thread that's waiting for the lock needs to allow the other thread to run, so it needs to yield. With userland threads, this can be done without a system call.

A semaphore is supposed to sleep until the lock becomes ready. In the real world, sleeping by spinning is rarely acceptable. Sleeping almost always requires a system call: the kernel moves the waiting thread out of the scheduler's ready list and onto the wait list for the semaphore object.